# Why Integer.parseInt of a String representing a number throws java.lang.NumberFormatException in J2ME?

Tags: java, string, numbers

I want to sum the values of four columns of a `recordstore`. The values in these four columns are numbers with the `decimal point` , for example `30.00`; the `recordstore` row is a `csv-like` data with which I use a userdefined function to get the value of a particular column: so I get a `String` for the four columns , for example `"30.00"`. Now I want to `sum` these four values ; so I must `convert` them into `int` ! But when I attempt to use `Integer.parseInt` then the `java.lang.NumberFormatException` is raised ! So how to make the sum in this situation ?

Comment: Either my astigmatism is getting worse, or you really like backticks.

Comment: `30.00` isn't an `integer` because there's a `decimal` `point`.

Comment: From a mathematical perspective, 30.00 is an integer last time I checked. Question is completely justifiable imo.

Comment: As you have a decimal point number in String you should use the `Double.parseDouble()`.

Comment: I don't think anybody has claimed it isn't a justified question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though `30.00` seems like an integer to you, Java thinks it looks like a floating point value (due to the decimal point).

You therefore need to parse it as a double, and then get the integer part.

```
int i = Double.parseDouble("30.00").intValue();
```

(Not J2ME specific by the way.)

Answer (score 1):

If your numbers contain decimal points, you need to parse as a double.

```
Double.parseDouble("30.00");
```

From there you can use `Math` methods or just truncate to get your Integer.

Answer (score 0):

Just as another alternative, you could also use `Integer.parseInt("30.00".split("\\.")[0])`
This would remove dependency on decimal separator (if you **always** have a dot in string, but you have **no control on locale** it will be parsed on.